# Opening a PDF from the assets folder on a button press in a tab fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have an Android app with 3 tabs. I want to put a CardView that when clicked opens a PDF from the assets folder (through intents).

Right now I have a button in one of the tabs that shows a toast when tapped, so I know it works. How do I go about making it so that tapping the button opens a PDF from the assets folder instead?

I've read a ton of answers on stackoverflow but none of them seemed to work for me. I think it might be because I have a MainActivity.java file, and 3 other TabFragment.java files, and there's something I'm not doing right. Or maybe it's something completely different, I don't know.

Here is my MainActivity.java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;

private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Starting.");

    mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "TAB1");
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab2Fragment(), "TAB2");
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab3Fragment(), "TAB3");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}}
```

Tab1Fragment.java code is:

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {


private static final String TAG = "Tab1Fragment";

private Button btnTEST;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_fragment, container, false);
    btnTEST = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnTEST);

    btnTEST.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TESTING BUTTON CLICK 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




        }
    });

    return view;

}}
```

and tab1_fragment.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:onClick="cardView1"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="Tab1"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/textTab1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnTEST"
        android:text="TESTBTN 1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your Button click event put this code.

```
btnTEST.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TESTING BUTTON CLICK 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile()+"/pdfname.pdf");
        if (file.exists())
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        try
        {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Application available to view pdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }
      }


   }
});
```

Hope, It will help you...

Comment: I added your code after the line of my toast message (I commented it out to check if the toast in your code would show). The toast message in your code displays on button press but unfortunately doesn't do anything else. I recall most of the answers here about reading files from the assets folder mentioning `AssetManager` and `getAssets();`, so I think that's needed too.

Comment: Is it working or not??..If not working then tell me what is the problem.

Comment: Accidentally pressed enter before typing the whole thing, Anyway, I added your code after the line of my toast message (I commented it out to check if the toast in your code would show). The toast message in your code displays on button press but unfortunately doesn't do anything else. I recall most of the answers here about reading files from the assets folder mentioning `AssetManager` and `getAssets();` so I think that's needed somewhere too.